# Select UNIX_TIMESTAMP() returns strange JSON key

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

I am storing TIMESTAMPs in MySQL and returning them using a query similar to:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(field)...
```

It works, but upon returning them using json_encode my `key: value` shows up as `"UNIX_TIMESTAMP(orders.time)":"1357453256"`. I'm not sure how to use this in Javascript.

So my question is, how do I get JS to interpret this key:value pair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the results of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` an alias:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(field) AS field ...
```

Your resulting JSON should look like:

```
"field":"1357453256"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the square bracket notation:

```
var timestamp = json.foo.bar.["UNIX_TIMESTAMP(orders.time)"];
```